# How to protect in-app purchases on ROOTED Android device?

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-security

If a device is rooted there are a lot of apps on the Play Market like `Hide Root`.

I have disabled `in-app-billing` if the device is rooted by `Fabric`'s built-in method.

It does not work if I'm using such apps.

Comment: You should not disable in-app purchase on rooted devices. It's not fair for users who rooted their devices. In general protecting IAB is not necessary, because user, who wants to hack IAB, will not pay any money.

Comment: TOP, this users affecting my service stability. They buying a lot of coins for free by hacking in-app purchasing on rooted devices. And other users feels bad because of this actions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on the client for security, because it is impossible to detect rooting in general when running in an environment that is trying to hide itself from you.

If you have a server, do verification on the server.